# What kinds of files can be added to Documents in the Cloud?

Tags: macos, iwork, icloud

I already know that Pages can add .doc files too, but my knowledge ends at that. Does anyone have an exhaustive list of files that can be added to Documents in the Cloud **through Apple apps (Preview, iWork, TextEdit, etc) only?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you consider the **Finder** to be an Apple app, the answer is **any arbitrary file**.

From my experimentation, it appears files dropped into folders in the `~/Library/Mobile Documents` hierarchy get synched to other computers using the same iCloud account, regardless of type.

Comment: This is "technically" an unsupported feature. It's been postulated that Apple might be prepping for a dropbox competitor.

Comment: Sure, it's unsupported. But as of now, it works quite well.